# the ... assembly

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm not a native English speaker and need your help for the meaning of the word "assembly". I would like to use it for the name of an online-store. It's a online-store for curated, high quality/luxury consumer goods. I would like to use it instead of "collection", for example: "The Artworks Assembly". Is that possible? I ask because I know "assembly" is used like "assembly line in the automotive parts industry" or for "Assembly" used like "The National Assembly for Wales" or "General Assembly" (an assembly of humans), but is it also possible to use it for products? I hope you understand what I'd like to use it for.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may use it however you wish, but it's likely to mislead your customers, who will be used to the usages you cite.  Check out the word *assemblage*.  It may be closer to what you want.

Comment: Some people will see *assembly* in the sense of the ​process of putting together the ​parts of a ​structure, and may wonder whether they have to [construct the goods themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready-to-assemble_furniture) or whether you are offering to do so for them.

Answer (score 1):

The word **assembly** seems to suggest the grouping of a set of objects or people into a unit, or a specific, single thing.

> The assembly line in an automotive plant assembles *the car*.
>   The National Assembly of the *Welsh Government* [a single governmental unit]
>   The school assembly [the group of people that together constitute the school]

So, I don't think **assembly** is appropriate for your intended use, at least not in the way the word **collection** might be used when referring to a fashion or luxury goods *collection*.

**Collection** is a good option, but if you don't like it, try one of these instead:

- **range** [as in the summer *range*]
- **line** [as in sportswear *line*]
- **label** [as in the Tommy Hilfiger *label*]
- **brand** [as in the Tommy Hilfiger *brand*]